# Do different iphones have the same accelerometer axes?

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, direction

I was wondering if two different iPhones would have the same accelerometer axes. I know the Z axes would be pointing in the same direction because the accelerometer uses the acceleration of gravity but would the X and Y axes be pointing the same way respectively?  For example if iPhone 1 accelerated east and the corresponding accelerator reading was in the X direction, would iPhone 2's acceleration North be in the Y direction? Or would it be in whatever direction the iPhone is calibrated to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axes use the device as a reference, see this from the docs on [UIAcceleration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html)

[image: iPhone accelerometer axis]

Comment: Is there a way to use the compass sensor to make an app the finds the relative acceleration in cardinal directions?  like if i were to use the compass to tell the iphone what directions north east south and west are and then use the accelerometer to read which cardinal direction it accelerated in?

Comment: Perhaps use the gyroscope as well to account for possible yaw and spin which would change the accelerometer direction?

Comment: The magnetometer (compass) will give you data along the same axes  so yes, you should be able to infer which axes of the device points towards the magnetic north. You will need to make this computation yourself, but it shouldn't be overly complicated.